# Lagging a quadratic independent variable

Tags: multivariate-analysis, panel-data, nonlinear-regression, instrumental-variables, lags

In the theoretical framework for my model, there is concern about reverse causality between Y and my main X variable. Additionally, I believe there's an information lag effect where economic agents are not responding to a situation contemporaneously, they are using past information to inform their current decisions. Therefore, any predicted values for Y would be reliant on the observed values of X from the past period. Lagging this X variable would be dealing with the reverse causality concern and incorporating the information lag effect hypothesis discussed in some of the literature.

However, my Y and X have a non-linear relationship. To address this, I am using a quadratic fit for my main model and, as a supplementary note, producing regression spline results to better discuss coefficients on X.

In this case, to perform IV regression would I have to lag both the linear and quadratic variables?

Would it be better practice to only perform IV with my regression splines?

Comment: Are you talking about using $X_{t-1}$ as an instrument for $X$?

Comment: @shadowtalker yes, that's what I'm referring to.